# How to find the canonical form of an eliptic paraboloid

Tags: calculus, geometry

I must find the canonical form of the eliptic paraboloid $4x^2+y^2-8y-2z+22=0$

I know that the canonical form is given by:

$$\frac{(x-i)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-j)^2}{b^2}=(z-k)$$

How can I find this form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete the square

$$4x^2  + \left( y - 4 \right)^2  + 6 - 2z= 0$$

divide all terms by $2$

$$
2x^2  + \frac{{\left( {y - 4} \right)^2 }}{2} = z - 3
$$

write in the canonical form as
$$\frac{{x^2 }}
{{\frac{1}
{2}}} + \frac{{\left( {y - 4} \right)^2 }}
{2} = z - 3$$

Answer (score 0):

For $z=k$ you will be able to complete the square in $x,y$, which actually will be only in $y$, so $k$ is ...